# Convert list to matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of objects [A, B, C, D]
I want to create a matrix such that

```
  A B C D
A
B
C
D
```

while value in each matrix cell is computed using some logic (like entry for (col A, row B) is (A.val - B.Val)

I can write a function to do this. But I have a feeling that this can be done in a easier and better way.

How to do this easily in python? (probably using numpy?)
Also what are search terms I should use to find such operations?

Comment: If you read it as a numpy array, you can use the [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method to change the dimensions of the array

Comment: OP wants a custom tensordot product, not a reshape..

Comment: Can you be more specific about those objects?  It's easiest (and fastest) when the lists are simple numeric ranges ([0,1,2,...]), and the logic is mathematical (plus, times, etc).

Comment: Have you read a basic `numpy` tutorial like https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this is with a nested list comprehension. The operation is the expression in the innermost list comprehension and can be easily changed.

```
>>> vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> matrix = [[x - y for x in vals] for y in vals]
>>> matrix
    [[ 0,  1,  2, 3],
     [-1,  0,  1, 2],
     [-2, -1,  0, 1],
     [-3, -2, -1, 0]]
```

Here I used subtraction between elements to match your example, but note that this syntax accepts any arbitrary operation between objects:

```
matrix = [[obj1.some_operation(obj2) for obj1 in vals] for obj2 in vals]
```

If you need to work with `matrix` in numpy later on, you can always cast it into a `numpy.array()`.

Comment: I was trying to get numpy to do it too, can't find an easy way. I think this is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for adding arbitrary operation. My program has complex operation theere.

Comment: `np.arange(4)-np.arange(4)[:,None]` produces this matrix as well.  But this approach only works for operations that accept whole arrays, not ones that require scalar `i,j` inputs.